# Getting most frequent terms in a subset of indexed lucene documents

Tags: solr, lucene, tag-cloud, word-cloud

Let's assume the following scenario.

- Lucene document: ArticleDocument

  Fields: {Id, text, publisherId}
- A publisher can publish multiple articles.

**Problem**

I would like to build word clouds (most frequent words, shingles) for each ***Publisher Id***.

After my investigation, I could find ways to get most frequent terms for the entire Index or a document but not for *a subset of documents.* I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195434/how-can-i-get-top-terms-for-a-subset-of-documents-in-a-lucene-index) but that's Lucene 2.x and I'm hoping there exists an effective way in recent Lucene.

Please could you guide me with a way to perform that in **Lucene 4.x** (preferred) or 3.x (latest in version 3).

Please note that I cannot make each Publisher a document with all the articles being appended to a field.

That's because I would like to have those words in the cloud to be searchable with corresponding articles (by same publisher id) being the results.

I'm not sure whether maintaining two types of lucene documents (article and publisher) is a good idea in terms of maintenance and performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Pivot Faceting available in Solr 4.X releases. Pivot faceting allows you to facet within the results of the parent facet.

Generate Shingled token for "text" field at indexing time using [Shingle Filter Factory.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory)

For faceting add `facet=true&facet.pivot=publisherid,text` parameters in your query.

Sample query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.pivot=publisherid,text
```

Query will return frequent shingles/words with frequency for each "publisherid".

Comment: I never imagined that I could get it done by an out of the box feature. Thanks a lot for pointing out the facets feature.

Comment: If you don't mind, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885764/lucene-analyzer-chain-shinglefilter-without-filler-tokens

Comment: Hi.. @phani sorry for being late in response :( Added my answer :)