# Lucene Analyzer chain: ShingleFilter without filler tokens

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search, facet

In my analyzer chain, ShingleFilter comes after stopword filter. As mentioned in the [docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html), ShingleFilter handles position increments > 1 by inserting filler tokens (tokens with termtext "_").

```
For example : "please divide this sentence into biword shingles" 

Shingles of size 2 : please divide, divide _, _ sentence, sentence _, _ biword, biword shingles (assuming that "this, "into" are stopwords)
```

I would like to eliminate those shingles with the filler tokens, i.e. my desired output contains only: please divide, biword shingles.

I've a dedicated field for facets with shingles up to 4-grams. Due to these stopwords, all the facet constraints (or values) look useless with those fillers like **"divide _ sentence _"**

Please could you guide me.

Using Solr 4.4.

*UPDATE*

I thought of setting enablePositionIncrement to false in StopFilter configuration. Not sure whether that solves the problem or not but Lucene 4.4 doesn't support that anymore.

Comment: Setting `enablePositionIncrement` to false was definitely the right thought, yes.  It was news to me that it's no longer supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `PatternReplaceFilterFactory` in your analyzer chain after `ShingleFilterFactory`. Replace all Token containing filler token with empty string i.e. "".

This may solve your problem temporarily but for permanent solution have to write your own analyzer or customize ShingleFilter.

Sample FieldType:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_shingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">     
        <analyzer>
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />       
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>           
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=".*_.*" replacement=""/>       
    </analyzer>     
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: brilliant, works like a charm. I was going to write a FilteringTokenFilter to eliminate all the tokens with that pattern. Now I know that it is available out of the box for testing purpose (only) as I will eventually have to get rid of empty tokens emitted by PatternReplaceFilter.

Comment: hi @phani.. Another solution can be: don't apply StopWordsFilter and remove shingles which starts with stopwords or ends with stopwords using suitable regex pattern in PatternReplaceFilter... Can try for your testing purpose... :)

Comment: Enhancement: Use `ShingleFilterFactory` with `fillerToken="___"`, then use for replacement `pattern=".*___.*"`. This will make sure that user token with `_` will not be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

[`PositionFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/position/PositionFilterFactory.html) should do the job.  It is deprecated (see the [Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/position/PositionFilter.html), for why), but it should work.

```
...
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>           
<filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory" positionIncrement="1"/>       
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true"/>
```

Make sure you apply it at both query and index time, of course.

That said, are you sure you need this?  Since the positionIncrements should be applied in similar ways at query and index time, having them will generally be helpful.  Are you seeing particular problems when querying the index?  Or just seeing strange things in debug output?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that. I hate to lose positional metadata as it may rebound as a future requirement. At the moment, all my facet constraints look really non-informative with those underscores.

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 4.7 release, you have the option to override the default filler token of "_". You could set it to an empty space. The configuration will be like :

```
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true" fillerToken=""/>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that you will still get ngrams for filler tokens, just that the string used will be emty, so for the word "a word on" given that you have a length filter with min 3, you'll get two digramms: " word" and "word on".

Comment: Even worse, the duplicates (as reported by Yeti) cannot be removed using a `RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory`.